# Send Message to Net (Similar to net send)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Im not sure whether this topic have been disscussed or not, but i have no idea what to do. In c#, i need to send message to other people in my networks. I made some researches, and all pointing to socket methods. With this method, logically it will work like this:

1. open up socket
2. Encode the message(to ascii for example)
3. Put the encoded bytes in an array
4. Send over the array
5. On the other side there's also a socket opened, and then it's the same thing in reverse order.

So i found this code, Can anyone help me understanding the code, which are similar on what i want:

```
   IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any,9999);
   //no.1
   Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
   socket.Bind(ip);
   socket.Listen(10);
   Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a client...");
   Socket client = socket.Accept();
   IPEndPoint clientep =(IPEndPoint)client.RemoteEndPoint;
   Console.WriteLine("Connected with {0} at port {1}",clientep.Address, clientep.Port);
   //no.2 & 3
   string welcome = "Welcome";
   byte[] data = new byte[1024];
   data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(welcome);
   //no.4
   client.Send(data, data.Length,SocketFlags.None);
   while(true)
   {
     data = new byte[1024];
     int receivedDataLength = client.Receive(data);
     Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength));
     client.Send(data, receivedDataLength, SocketFlags.None);
   }
   Console.WriteLine("Disconnected from {0}",clientep.Address);
   client.Close();
   socket.Close();
```

I manage to understand what the code do until point no 4. but this code:

```
while(true)
   {
     data = new byte[1024];
     int receivedDataLength = client.Receive(data);
     Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength));
     client.Send(data, receivedDataLength, SocketFlags.None);
   }
```

I'm not sure what the above codes do? 
and for the point no 5, can someone explain in to me how to do that? is that mean, that i need another program as a receiver?

~Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

The code you're looking at is for an echo server, which reads some data sent to a socket by another client, prints it to the console, and then sends it back to the client that it came from.  This is what the code in point 5 does.  Here's what is going on:

data = new byte[1024];
this is just allocating a buffer to hold the data that we're going to read.

int receivedDataLength = client.Receive(data);
this receives data from the socket.  Receive is a blocking call, so it won't return until there is data to be read OR until the socket is disconnected or has an error, at which point it throws.  The recievedDataLength variable is EXTREMELY important because this tells us how many bytes we actually read.  The number of bytes read may easily be LESS than the size of the buffer, because we don't know how many bytes were sent to the socket by the other client.  By detecting how many bytes were read, we can be sure that we know how much data is actually in our buffer.  If this returns 0, it means that the connection was closed by the other side.

Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, receivedDataLength));
This just converts the buffer from arbitrary byte values to an ASCII string.  Note that receivedDataLength allows us to only write out a string for the number of bytes that were read from the socket.  If we just wrote the contents of the entire buffer, you'd get random crap on the console since any data present in the buffer that occurs AFTER receivedDataLenth is unknown.

client.Send(data, receivedDataLength, SocketFlags.None);
Finally, we're sending the data back to the other end of the connection by writing it to the socket.  We use receivedDatalength to indicate that we only want to send the bytes that we actually read instead of the whole buffer.  If you were sending a different message here, you'd want to use the length in bytes of the message that you're sending.  You'll most likely never need to set any SocketFlags so don't worry about these.

Now this code here is for a server that wants to receive connections.  To make a connection, the code is very similar, except after you call Socket.Bind(ip) you'll call Socket.Connect(remotehost) instead of Listen() and Accept().  Then the code to write data to the Socket is the same as in step 5 above.

One last thing:  the Socket.Accept() method is non-intuitive at first so I'll explain what it's doing.  Calling Listen() tells the socket to allow incoming connections, but in order to actually use those connections for something, you have to accept them.  Accept() blocks until a new connection is made, then it returns a NEW socket object.  This socket is similar to the socket that you're listening on, except that this socket represents a socket-pair, meaning that on the other end of the connection there is another similar socket that is going to talk to this one.  You should use this new socket to talk to the client that has connected.

Once you've gotten the new Socket from Accept(), you still have the old socket, which is the one you originally called Accept() on.  This socket is still listening for new connections, so if you want to allow more machines to connect to this socket, you need to keep calling Accept() until you are no longer willing to accept connections (like if you don't want there to be more than some arbitrary number of connections) or until you want to shut down the application.  Now I said before that Accept() is a blocking call, so if you call it again it will not allow the thread you're on to do anything else until a new connection comes in.  This means that you need to do one of two things:  Either call BeginAccept to accept new clients asynchronously, OR use BeginRead or BeginSend to handle your socket I/O asynchronously.  You CANNOT do both of these things on the same thread.  It's a bit harder to do this, but check out the IPv6Sockets sample on MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8sd71sfs(VS.80).aspx) and you can see how this is done.  Remember, it is absolutely necessary that you do NOT try to accept new connections and perform I/O on existing connections on the same thread.  I actually recommend that you do everything with your sockets asynchronously.

If you don't want to have to use all this socket stuff, you can also check out the TcpClient class.  It's a thin wrapper around Socket that allows you to grab a Stream object from the TcpClient and just read/write from that stream.  It's way easier to use but it's not as powerful as a Socket, although for your application I doubt you'll need to use anything fancy with Sockets anyway so TcpClient is what I would use.

Comment: Hi, sorry, but kind of a bit lost on ur explanation. can make it short or provide me with some readings or references? i'm not prefer references in MSDN coz the explanation seems to advance for me to understand. thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's sitting in a loop receiving data and writing it to the console, and echoing back to the sender.